# typescript fail to catch incompatible generic type error

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

I want to create a function that can handle feature object of generic type. The code is as follow

```js
interface ComplexTypeMap {
    featureA: { name: string },
    featureB: { age: number }
}

function testComplexTypeMap<K extends keyof ComplexTypeMap>(
typeName: K, value: ComplexTypeMap[K]) { }

const featureA = { name: 'John' };
const featureB = { age: 18 };

testComplexTypeMap('featureA', featureA);
testComplexTypeMap('featureA', featureB); // #marker1, good catch, expected behavior


interface Settings<K extends keyof ComplexTypeMap> {
    featureName: K,
    value: ComplexTypeMap[K]
}

function testComplexTypeMapSetting<K extends keyof ComplexTypeMap>
(typeName: K,   value: Settings<K>) { }

const settingsA: Settings<'featureA'> = { featureName : 'featureA', value : featureA};
const settingsB: Settings<'featureB'> = { featureName : 'featureB', value : featureB};

testComplexTypeMapSetting('featureA', settingsA);
testComplexTypeMapSetting('featureA', settingsB); // #marker2, why not catch the error, unexpected
```

At marker1, the error is expected, and it is good. So I expected, error should be throw at marker2, but it did not. Strangely, actually typescript kind of know that type I should use in marker2, showing some intellisense like the picture attached. But it just accept settingsB without throwing any warning. Why is that?
The code above can be run at [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHANhADwBUBPbCAWTm2QG8BYAKAEgYI4wBXKCAQQC46yEHEwRBAZzBRQAc2QBfADRNW7LjwBCg2sjizxwzpgBG0RUwVMmMTiARhg6EMkhSMOfMTKVqAHgBpZEJIEAATCWQAawgSdBg0LDxCUnIqbAA%20AAowHwA5UUMApWQANzhcTkMPZO806gBtAIBdAEohK0YmBGcpZDYObj5kAF4hETFBAHIAKXQACxApxQBubt6wfvUhzVGhfUMARgAOVetGNzAar1TfbCypgY0%20KZKnod5WtYuIdySbnzpB7vHi8V5bQZaL7IAD0MOQAGJMHAoDEoIcSrJ0OgwsgEBwEPMSoRyA4ILizPM4KUnFBzkxQJBYIgUABlCBgRwgWQSQLBAihCLRWLxRKeFKA6gZOiqEEQAqTZDFVTlSrVf4S%20rYJrNSznWz2RzOVy-K4aup3dmcuR8kIQcKRGJxBLXTV3bK5cgKopKZiqqqCK1cnmBDLtXSddYgPoSDnBiQCZBBuS8x7bUFTaVjXRy73IaZysElf0oQSFhTfHrRzax63ciTaJNxlN%20NOQiCaTN7HPp%20WFfPINvPTvFipVAdyzQV86XV0W9LJ7nA3tF5C1%20Ofb6z823BfNpdDj7g9cpzTQuGI5Go6AAJhKAHd5iRhOhNviwITXPMUNAoOgoCUdgkhAZJhEwQA)
[image]

Comment: It is a little difficult for me explain at the moment, but this seems to work: `function testComplexTypeMapSetting<K extends keyof ComplexTypeMap, V extends Settings<K>>(typeName: K,   value: V) { }` See: https://tsplay.dev/9WvLBN

Comment: It has to do with how Indexed Access and Generics resolve union. Possibly discussed here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014 @jcalz enlighten please? :D